# Sharing Rules in Salesforce

Tags: sharing

I have the following requirement.

In my organization i have 3 users. Let the first user is say UserA and he is admin. Second UserB and third UserC are one role below the Admin. Now I want the UserB's Account records should not be visisble to UserC and UserC's Account records should not be visible to UserB. 
I have done this by following step:
1. i have made my OWD settings for Account object to private.
Now i have some contacts. 
Now i want OwnerB should see the contacts only for the Accounts he own even though he is not the owner of that contacts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Contact OWD to "controlled by parent" and you'll allow your users to see all contacts on accounts they own. You could also make a sharing rule if you only want User B to be affected.

Comment: I have done the same. But still i can see the UserB's records when i login as UserC. In simple when i login as UserB i should only see UserB's records and i should not be able to see UserC's records and even in global search i should not find them.

Comment: Log in as admin, check one contact that C has access to that belongs to B, and click on the sharing button. There is a Why? link that explains which rules or records are granting access to B's contacts to C. I believe you need to click Expand to see the Why? link.